# Error matching Expected type with actual type in function

Tags: haskell

I keep getting a Couldn't match expected type Card with actual type [Card] in the first argument of getnumfrmcard (xs) and second argument of (<) namely getnumfrmcard(xs) in the function straight(checks to see if a hand of a cards is a straight)

```
enter code here
  data Card = Cards (Suit,Face) deriving (Eq)
  data Hand=  Hands[Card]

   straight:: Hand->Bool
   straight (Hands [] )                                     =True
   straight (Hands (x:xs) )                
            | null(xs)==True                          = True
            | getnumfrmcard (x)  < getnumfrmcard (xs) =straight (Hands xs)
            | otherwise                               = False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error indicates that the function `getnumfrmcard` expects an argument of type `Card` but is given a `[Card]` (a list of cards). The culprit is the second to last line where you have `getnumfrmcard (xs)`. If you match a list against `(x:xs)` then `x` becomes the head of the list (a single element) and `xs` becomes the tail, which is a list. so in

```
f []     = []
f (x:xs) = xs

f [1,2,3] -- [2,3]
```

`xs` is bound to `[2,3]`.

You could match against `(Hands (x0:x1:xs))` but then you need to decide how to deal with a list that only has one argument (I haven't thought about what you're trying to do really).

Also note: You usually don't need parenthesis around function arguments in Haskell, so instead of `getnumfrmcard (xs)` you want to write `getnumfrmcard xs`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to check whether or not you have a straight, it is not enough to check whether each card is lower than the next, it has to be *one* lower.

A more Haskell-y solution comes to mind :

```
straight (Hands cards) = and $ zipWith nextStraight cards (tail cards)
   where nextStraight c c' = getnumfrmcard c' == getnumfrmcard c+1
```

`zipWith nextStraight cards (tail cards)` will combine every pair of adjacent elements in `cards` by the function `nextStraight` (a function that checks if two cards are of adjacent values). Then we combine the resulting boolean list by requiring that *all* pairs must verify the predicate (hence the `and` function).

Of course, the hand must be sorted beforehand in order for this method to work, otherwise some straights won't be detected ([2H,3D,5S,4D,6C], for example).

Answer (score 0):

Coding in haskell is not that obvious, I would put more code into your question so you will not end up with more questions :) So the answer based on Paul answer could look like this i think.

```
module Test where

data Card = Cards (Int, Int) deriving (Eq, Ord)
data Hand = Hands [Card]

straight :: Hand -> Bool
straight (Hands [] ) = True
straight (Hands [x0] ) = True
straight (Hands (x0:x1:xs) )
    | null(xs) == True = True
    | x0 < x1 = straight (Hands xs)
    | otherwise = False

main :: IO ()
main = print $ straight $ Hands [Cards (5,1), Cards(4,4)]
```

Feel free to edit this